# python regex find number of a specific length following at some point after search string

Tags: python, regex

EDIT: I may have solved my problem using a negative lookbehind, but I am a) worried I've just stumbled across a special case where this works, or b) have it ~correct but extremely stilted / inefficient.  Would VERY much appreciate any feedback, and I'd really like to understand why the original pattern wasn't working.  Here's the regex pattern that now seems to be working:

`qtD = re.compile('qt[^cy].*?(?<!\<|\>|\d)(\d{3})(?:\D|$)', re.I)`

Below is the original message:

I am trying to accomplish the following in Python (3.2) using the standard regular expression package, re.  This doesn't seem like it should be complicated, but I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Here's an example string:
`s = 'EKG done this AM with QT 560 and QTC wnl at 535ms, higher than on exam performed 5/3/2015 which showed...`

What I'm trying to have returned by `re.findall()` in this case is simply the number '560' - that is, the first number appearing at some point after 'QT' and being in the form of a 3 digit integer.

Here's the regex pattern I'm currently using:

`qtD = re.compile('qt[^cy].*?[^\<\>\d](\d{3})(?:\D|$)', re.I)`

...so, basically:

- find QT (but not QTC or QTY)
- ...possibly followed by any number of characters
- ...and return the first 3 digit integer you find (\d{3})
- ...but only if that 3 digit integer is not immediately preceded by "<", ">", or another digit
- ...and is immediately followed by either the end of the line, $, or a non-digit, \D

I'm searching like this:
`re.findall(qtD, s)`

The above works fine but ONLY in the case that there is a string (characters or whitespace) that has a length of at least 2 between the 'QT' and the number.  In other words, "QT560" returns 560.  "QT interval normal at 560" returns 560.  "QT: 560" returns 560.

BUT, if the string is as shown above, "...QT 560...", then the regex will keep reading and return the next 3 digit number, 535.

I have tried other things, like making the `[^\<\>\d]` lazy, i.e., `[^\<\>\d]?` or repeating 0 or 1 times `[^\<\>\d]{0,1}` but then it will start doing things like returning the "015" from 5/3/2015 if it doesn't find any 3 digit numbers earlier than that, i.e., if 560 and 535 weren't there, in which case I'd want an empty list returned.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: ...the part above that reads "In other words, "QT560" should actually read, "In other words, `QT  560`"  (two spaces between QT and 560)

Answer (score 2):

In your pattern you are matching at least 2 characters with `[^cy]` and `[^\<\>\d]`

Instead you might use 2 lookaround assertions:

```
\bqt(?![cy]).*?(?<![\d<>])(\d{3})(?:\D|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bqt` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match, then match `qt`
- `(?![cy])` Negative lookahead, assert not `c` or `y` directly to the right
- `.*?` Match any character, as few as possible
- `(?<![\d<>])` Negative lookbehind, assert not a digit or `<` or `>` to the left
- `(\d{3})` Capture 3 digits in **group 1** *(returned by re.findall)*
- `(?:\D|$)` Match either a non digit or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IgcWav/1)

This will then also match `560` in `QT560` as it can be

> possibly followed by any number of characters

Or matching the 3 digits first, and then the lookbehind assertion:

```
\bqt(?![cy]).*?(\d{3})(?<![\d<>]\d{3})(?:\D|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A7Nu57/1)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the problem is this section

```
[^cy]    # requires 1 character
.*? 
[^<>\d]  # requires 1 character
```

requires  a minimum of 2 characters between `qt` and `\d[3]`

whereas, this

```
[^cy]        # requires 1 character
.*?
(?<![<>\d])  # requires 0 character
```

requires  a minimum of 1 characters between `qt` and `\d[3]`

Since there is only 1 character between `QT 560` this regex
`qt[^cy].*?[^<>\d](\d{3})(?:\D|$)` will only match `QT 560 and QTC wnl at 535m`
in your sample string, where `535` is in capture group 1.

You can see this if you add another space inbetween `QT  560`
https://regex101.com/r/yMMjtD/1

This might better solve the problem, or similar
`qt(?![cy]).+?(?<![<>\d])(\d{3})(?:\D|$)`
https://regex101.com/r/JjB7kL/1

Answer (score 0):

> *"find QT (but not QTC or QTY)"*

```
QT(?![CY])
```

> *"possibly followed by any number of characters"*

```
QT(?![CY])[^\d]*
```

> *"and return the first 3 digit integer you find (\d{3})"*

```
QT(?![CY])[^\d]*(\d{3})
```

> *"but only if that 3 digit integer is not immediately preceded by "<", ">", or another digit"*

I'm not sure I understand, *"or another digit"*, as, the first digit would have been matched by *\d{3}*.

```
QT(?![CY])[^\d]*(?<!<|>)(\d{3})
```

> *"and is immediately followed by either the end of the line, $, or a non-digit, \D"*

```
QT(?![CY])[^\d]*(?<!<|>)(\d{3})(?:$|\D)
```

For example, the following *string* values will contain a match, and capture the value *"560"*.

```
EKG done this AM with QT 560 and QTC wnl at 535ms, higher than on exam performed 5/3/2015 which showed...
EKG done this AM with QT560 and QTC wnl at 535ms, higher than on exam performed 5/3/2015 which showed...
EKG done this AM with QT: 560 and QTC wnl at 535ms, higher than on exam performed 5/3/2015 which showed...
EKG done this AM with QT abc 560 and QTC wnl at 535ms, higher than on exam performed 5/3/2015 which showed...
EKG done this AM with QT560
EKG done this AM with QT560a
```

And, these will not.

```
EKG done this AM with QTC 560 and QTC wnl at 535ms, higher than on exam performed 5/3/2015 which showed...
EKG done this AM with QTY 560 and QTC wnl at 535ms, higher than on exam performed 5/3/2015 which showed...
EKG done this AM with QT >560 and QTC wnl at 535ms, higher than on exam performed 5/3/2015 which showed...
EKG done this AM with QT <560 and QTC wnl at 535ms, higher than on exam performed 5/3/2015 which showed...
EKG done this AM with QT 5601 and QTC wnl at 535ms, higher than on exam performed 5/3/2015 which showed...
EKG done this AM with QT 56 and QTC wnl at 535ms, higher than on exam performed 5/3/2015 which showed...
```

Comment: `$` in `[$\D]` doesn't mean "end of line". It means a literal `$`.

Comment: @InSync, thanks, I changed it to a group.